# How can we modify the properties of model after an event in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Suppose there is an model with properties id and count.

```
public class Item {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

I want to generate an event by creating a button so that I can increment the count of the object with given `id` (initially `count = 0`). I am new to Asp.NET MVC. So Please help me out.

Comment: do you need the counting for all user (application scope)? or only for the current user/connection?

Comment: I want it functioning for current user.